# programatically access a specified (customised) property of an episerver control

Tags: c#, properties, controls, episerver

What's a good way to programatically access a specified (customised) property of an episerver control  (supposing I have the control I need specified in a variable called control)
e.g. I am trying something like this control.GetProperty("CustomProperty1") but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which Episerver version is this?

Comment: Episerver 6 R2, sorry for missing this

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
var typedControl = control as YourControlType;
if (typedControl != null)
{
   var theProperty = typedControl.CustomProperty1;
}
```